# Calling requests_html or pyppeteer in Python multithreading ErrorError: signal only works in main thread

Tags: python, html, pyppeteer

I probably learned that the error was due to the use of coroutine io in pyppeteer and requests_html, which conflicted with multithreading, but I can't find a way to fix this.I don't speak English very much, I use google translation.

```
import asyncio
from pyppeteer import launch
from requests_html import HTMLSession

# Simulation using requests_html

def test1():
    session = HTMLSession()
    _r = session.get('http://bbs.tianya.cn/post-free-6085404-1.shtml' )
    _r.html.render()
    html = _r.html.html

    print(html)


# main
async def main():
    browser = await launch()
    page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto('http://example.com')
    await page.screenshot({'path': 'example.png'})
    await browser.close()


##The pyppeteer method is called at work
def aJob(arg):
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.run_until_complete(main())


## Multi-threaded task generation
def multiThread():
    from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
    cpus = 1  # 线程池大小

    pool = ThreadPool(cpus)
    _lstParam = range(0, 3)
    pool.map(aJob, _lstParam)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    multiThread()
```

I want to call pyppeteer or requests_html to simulate browsing the webpage in multithreading, but I always get the error "ValueError: signal only works in main thread" or "RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-1'." I have tried many methods, but I have been unable to run successfully.Please give me help, thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running pypupeteer in FLASK gives ValueError: signal only works in main thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53679905/running-pypupeteer-in-flask-gives-valueerror-signal-only-works-in-main-thread)

Answer (score 0):

Pyppeteer use signal to close the browser process but signal only works in main thread. If you don't really need this feature just set handleSIGINT,handleSIGTERM,handleSIGHUP to False on pyppeteer.launch method